# C# Directory.GetDirectories() return inexisting directory

Tags: c#, system.io.directory

I want to use Directory.GetDirectories(path) and then working with sub-directories but, when I start running my app, VS return me System.UnauthorizedAccessException. I can understand I fix this, no problem. The real problem is, as you can see in the linked picture, code try to acces a folder that doesn't exist.

In windows explorer I show all hide files and folder, and as you can see (again) when I go to the right spot in my PC, "Ma Musique" doesn't exist (and never existed by the way).

Where is folder come from and how can I deal with this ?

[image]

**EDIT :**

Code try to access this directory just after Lumion directory. As you see above, "Ma Musique" doesn't exist.

[image]

CMD (as administrator) doesn't find it too.
Directory.Exists() return true when give it "Ma musique" directory path.

Comment: So what is the value of `folderPath` here?

Comment: Did you upgrade this system from Windows 7? - it used to have a My Music folder for every user (English edition, obviously).

Comment: you'll notice in his screen shot, he translated to english for the question.

Comment: What tabbed File Explorer are you using to view the Documents folder? Note that "My Music" is a Junction Point and not an actual folder, and your application may be having trouble traversing it (it is there for backwards compatibility). They are also marked as Hidden and System, so you must enable viewing both.

Comment: @KlausGütter Input folder is "My Documents" directly selected from FolderPicker.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError No, it a propers windows 11 install.

Comment: "Ma Musique" by Joe Dassin was released by Sony BMG.  They were quite famous for their [rootkit scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal).

Comment: @Luuk What do you want me to debug ? File explorer correctly return C:\users\thoma\Documents and this this directory, there is no My Music directory.

Comment: You might try using [JunctionPoint.cs](https://gist.github.com/LGM-AdrianHum/260bc9ab3c4cd49bc8617a2abe84ca74) to determine if the directory is a junction point or not. You can do also get the target directory if you want to examine that as well.

Comment: Didu uncheck *“Hide protected operating system files (Recommended).”*?

Comment: @RufusLI will check your file thank. Where is this option ?

Comment: Directories like this tend to be ["super-hidden"](https://www.howtogeek.com/104825/make-a-super-hidden-folder-in-windows-without-any-extra-software/), they have the System and Hidden attributes turned on.  Use the [attrib command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib) to have a look and fix the problem.

Comment: I can't help but notice that the parent directory in the screenshot on the right is "Utilisateurs" and not "Users". Are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: Yes @JohnWu It is just translated.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried attrib in admin console but nothing appear..

Answer (score 1):

That is what is known as a "virtual" folder and it is there for backwards compatibility with old versions of Windows.  When users got their own music/video/etc folders, they were all turned into system virtual folders that don't actually exist at all as they are aggregates of content in multiple folders.  However programs that expect these folders to exist would break if they were missing so Windows would make a symbolic link that in some cases would allow a redirect.  I don't remember for sure but i think the redirect only worked if you were running as administrator.  In any case you can't browse into them as they aren't real.

Comment: Note technically these are Junction Points.

Comment: By default, these links cannot be accessed, but it's very easy to just restore the permissions on the links so they work normally.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing "acces denied" and/or do get this Exception "System.UnauthorizedAccessException".

Microsoft has a tool [ICACLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) that displays or modifies discretionary access control lists (DACLs) on specified files, and applies stored DACLs to files in specified directories.

Because of the mentioned error, you should investigate the response of:

```
icacls "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Ma musique"
```

(When you get an error about "Access denied", please execute this as Administrator)

The output of ICACLS should explain why you do no have access to that file/directory.

Comment: Thank you for providing help. This command show that me, admin, system, have full control on the directory but not everyone (I assume that as soon as I don't start my app as administrator I will get this error). That fine for me, I know that I should implement a thing like "If you don't have the permission, ask them to user".
The real problem I want to answer is just "Why I can't see this directory ?"

Comment: You cannot see the directory because of the "acces denied". The user "thoma" does not have enough rights to see that directory.

Comment: Of course it have, I the only user and administrator of the PC, how is it possible to me to not have access to it ? Result of your cmd command show this : 
-Everyone : DENY RD
-System : I OI CI F
-Admin : I OI CI F
-thoma : I OI CI F